# SQLite Manager: how to select columns in a table, keeping the count of the original occurrence of their values?

Tags: select, count, group-by, sqlitemanager

I am new to databases, and I am using the SQLite Manager Firefox add-on for a table like this:

```
rowid  |  col1  |  col2  |  col3  
  1    |   N    |   Y    |   N    
  2    |   N    |   N    |   N   
  3    |   N    |   Y    |   Y    
  4    |   N    |   Y    |   N
```

and I would like to reduce it to a table with a smaller number of columns (for instance 2) in the following way: each row should represent one possible combination of values (N,Y) of the 2 selected columns, associated with a count. This count should represent the number of rows in the original table where the other column assumed different values but the selected 2 columns have the given combination of values.
To be clear, if I select column 2 and 3, I would like to obtain:

```
col2  |  col3  | count  
 Y    |   N    |  2  
 N    |   N    |  1    
 Y    |   Y    |  1
```

while if I select columns 1 and 2:

```
col1  |  col2  | count  
 N    |   Y    |  3  
 N    |   N    |  1
```

I have tried to use a combination of commands such as COUNT and GROUP BY, but without reaching my goal. For instance, I`ve tried to use:

```
SELECT *, COUNT (*) AS count FROM table_test   
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

but it seems to work only for `col2`, giving me the # times `col2=Y` and the # times `col2=N`, but not in combination with `col3`...
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Your query looks OK. What is its output?

Comment: In the query, now I use "col2", "col3" and it seems to work. I think before it didn`t recognize the second column without the ". Thank you anyway

Comment: @CL.: the problem is that now I visualize all the columns and not only the ones I am interested in... I am trying with: `CREATE TABLE temp AS
SELECT col2, col3, count FROM (
SELECT *, COUNT (*) AS count 
FROM table_test
GROUP BY col2, col3 )`. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: This is not a forum. If you have a new question, ask a new question.